# What are the unk in IDA pseudo code?

Tags: ida, disassembly

I've open wsl.exe in IDA v7. With Tab key I open pseudocode of `sub_1400129F4` like this:

```
__int64 sub_1400129F4(__int64 a1, __int64 a2, __int64 a3, __int64 a4, ...) {
......

v8 = (__int64 *)sub_140011A40();
}
```

- The assembly of  `sub_140011A40()`:

```
sub_140011A40 proc near
lea     rax, unk_14001C2B0
retn
sub_140011A40 endp
```

- The pseudo code of `sub_140011A40()`:

```
void *sub_140011A40() {
  return &unk_14001C2B0;
}
```

- The `.data` sections shows this:

```
.data:000000014001C2AE                 db    0
.data:000000014001C2AF                 db    0
.data:000000014001C2B0 unk_14001C2B0   db    0                 ; DATA XREF: sub_140011A40↑o
.data:000000014001C2B1                 db    0
.data:000000014001C2B2                 db    0
.data:000000014001C2B3                 db    0
.data:000000014001C2B4                 db    0
.data:000000014001C2B5                 db    0
.data:000000014001C2B6                 db    0
.data:000000014001C2B7                 db    0
.data:000000014001C2B8 unk_14001C2B8   db    0                 ; DATA XREF: sub_140011A48↑o
.data:000000014001C2B9                 db    0
.data:000000014001C2BA                 db    0
```

- Question: What is the `unk` in that pseudo code or in that assembly? Does it hold the values of eight zeros from `.data` section?

Comment: post the assembly too interpreting a pseudo interpretation without context is tedious unk means unknown (may be someone writes there during runtime ?? and it is unknown at the moment  does assembly say mov eax, qword [unk]

Comment: so it is clear lea returns 14001C2B0 not the 0 lea is a speacial kind of move instruction that moves the address not the contents so v8 = 14001C2B0

Comment: forget the unk it is a label and it has no meaning in c or d or go it is a name given by ida to that specific address try pressing d on the address the unk will change to byte , press d again it will beome word press d again it will become dword etc etc  the code would be appromiximately v8 = &foo()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lea rax , unk___xxx 
ret
```

means the function returns the address not the contents

lea (load effective address ) is a special kind of mov instruction that load the address not the contents

the unk is a label ida could not decipher the type so it labelled the address as unk (possibly short form for unknown)

if you select that address and press **d** ida will replace the unk with byte 
if you press **d**  again ida will rename the byte to word  etc etc

basically from your pseudo code

the result would be `v8 = &foo()`

a screen shot where ida wasn't sure what the type was for a `CRITICAL_SECTION` pointer manually applying the structure to the address

[image]